# Picasso causes Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, picasso

I'm using Android studio and I'm trying to add [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library to my project, but whenever I try to run the app I'm having this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Here is my `Gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
//TODO::Update to the latest version of Play Service
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.8'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'ch.halarious:halarious-core:0.11'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:0.9.10@aar'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
compile 'com.integralblue:httpresponsecache:1.0.0'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.3’

//Here is the Picasso compile line
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
}
```

I' using the latest version of JDK for Mac "jdk-8u45-macosx-x64". BTW, I have tried those solutions (Clean, Build, restart) so no need to suggest them

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May you are facing the 65k method limit problem.
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

please put this in your default Config:

```
default Config {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and try again

Comment: Solved by adding only `multiDexEnabled true` to the default config section in Gradle